# SQLite - Fastest way to count inside selects

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application that makes quite a lot of selects, listing its results and allowing the user edit certain values.
The core of my question is if its possible to improve my queries or not given the following query in SQLite:

```
"SELECT X.data1, X.data2, count(X.id_X) as Quantity_Itens, 
(select count(*) from Table2 where id_X=X.id_X) local_Table2, 
(select count(*) from Table3 inner join Table2 on Table3.id_Table2 = Table2.id where Table3.id_X=X.id_X and type=1) Quantity_Type1, 
(select count(*) from Table3 inner join Table2 on Table3.id_Table2 = Table2.id where Table3.id_X=X.id_X and type=2) Quantity_Type2, 
(select count(*) from Table4 where id_X = X.id_X) Quantity_Other, 
(select count(*) from Table2 where id_X = X.id_X and status <10) Total_Data FROM Table1 X where (X.type_item = 2 or X.type_item = 4 or X.type_item = 6 or X.type_item = 8) and X.ative = 1 and id_local != 0 group by X.id_X order by X.Alias1"
```

I am not sure if using promisses will improve in any way this, as I need all those datas before allowing the user to take control again.
Also, may or may not be relevant:

- OS: Android 4+
- Frameworks: Ionic1, AngularJS, Cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query there are 5 subqueries executed for each of the rows of `Table1`.
Only one of them accesses only once 1 table.
2 of them access the same table twice and 2 of them access 2 joined tables twice.
This means there are multiple scans through the same tables for each  of the rows of Table1.
Also you are aggregating inside `Table1`, with `GROUP BY id_X`, but you have in the `SELECT` list 2 columns: `data1` and `data2`, which are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the returned values of these columns are arbitrary.
And what is that column `Alias1`? There is no such column among the returned columns of the query.

Anyway, I suggest that you aggregate first in each table, or join of tables and then join to `Table1`.
Like this:

```
SELECT t1.data1, 
       t1.data2, 
       t1.Quantity_Items, 
       t2.local_Table2, 
       t3.Quantity_Type1, 
       t3.Quantity_Type2, 
       t4.Quantity_Other, 
       t2.Total_Data 
FROM (
  -- The values returned for data1, data2 and Alias1 will be arbitrary
  SELECT id_X, data1, data2, Alias1, COUNT(*) Quantity_Items
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY id_X
) t1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_X, COUNT(*) local_Table2, SUM(status < 10) Total_Data
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY id_X
) t2 ON t2.id_X = t1.id_X
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t3.id_X, SUM(type = 1) Quantity_Type1, SUM(type = 2) Quantity_Type2
  FROM Table3 t3 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t3.id_Table2 = t2.id
  GROUP BY t3.id_X
) t3 ON t3.id_X = t1.id_X
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_X, COUNT(*) Quantity_Other
  FROM Table4
  GROUP BY id_X
) t4 ON t4.id_X = t1.id_X
WHERE t1.type_item IN (2, 4, 6, 8) 
  AND t1.active = 1 AND t1.id_local <> 0 
ORDER BY t1.Alias1
```

Comment: I am aware that its not the cleanest code ever, I had to change it quite a lot the names of tables and columns, since if remained as the original, it could bring me some trouble later, as the code is from a company that I work for. I will try it and see if solve my problem,

Comment: Hey, that helped. I now see that i made quite a wasteful query. Thanks for pointing it out, I guess that i can optimise others queries.